# Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: facebook, typeerror, registration, circular-dependency

We're using the `fb:registration plugin` to sign up users on our site. Today I noticed the registration redirect is no longer working in Google Chrome and Safari (latest public release). I know for sure it was working with the same code as recently as last week. It seems to be getting stuck on submission with this error, which is coming from:

`static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/ys/r/ioE9qOq_5Oa.js:101`

Firefox and IE have no problem, so it seems to be Webkit specific. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to note- it seems to only happen if you clear the prefilled FB form fields (by hitting the x).

Comment: It appears to only happen in recent versions of Chrome. Older ones work fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report tracking this on Facebook's developer site.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/251685364894450

Please go there and tell them you are seeing this issue too.

Comment: Hah, so I guess FB only notices stuff if you submit a bug report? 
Look at the timestamp on this. It's been up for over a week...

Comment: Voted up your bug report. Coincidentally, I added one yesterday too about an hour after this one.